# Prove that for $a ,b, c, d : a_{n+1} = |a_n-b_n| , b_{n+1} = |b_n-c_n|, c_{n+1} = |c_n-d_n|, d_{n+1} = |d_n-a_n|$ recursively results in $0,0,0,0$.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Please prove that:

For $a ,b, c, d : a_{n+1} = |a_n-b_n| , b_{n+1} = |b_n-c_n|, c_{n+1} = |c_n-d_n|, d_{n+1} = |d_n-a_n|$ repeated recursively results in $0,0,0,0$ .

The recursion happens all at once, so in effect $a_{n+1} = |a_n-b_n| , b_{n+1} = |b_n-c_n|, c_{n+1} = |c_n-d_n|, d_{n+1} = |d_n-a_n|$

For example,
$1 2 3 5, 1 1 2 4, 0 1 2 3, 1 1 1 3, 0 0 2 2, 0 2 0 2, 2 2 2 2, 0 0 0 0$
.

It would seem to work for all real numbers.

Comment: $1-2=-1$ not $1$.  Did you intend $a_{n+1}=|a_n-b_n|$ etc?

Comment: Totally omitted an important part! yes I did, fixing. Thank you

Comment: So these are integers? Is the recursion all at once, or does the $d=d-a$ use the new value of $a?$ Also, what are $a,b,c,d$ in your example?

Comment: Yes the recursion is all at once. Seems to work for all real numbers, editing.

Comment: Note use e.g. $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ to differ between each set of values.

Comment: Just playing with some numbers, starting with $94,56,35,23$ seemed to take $12$ steps, many more than most other examples I tried.

Comment: What if $a=1, b=\pi, c=\pi^2, d=\pi^3$?

Comment: @markvs after five steps, all four terms are $2(\pi-1)^2$ and so after six they are all $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following arguments works if $a_n,\dots$ are integers (so the conclusion also holds for rational by considering integers $ra_n,rb_n,rc_n,rd_n$ where $r\in\mathbb N$ is some number).

Let $a_n'=a_n-b_n,\,b_n'=b_n-c_n$ and so on.
Then $a_{n+1}'=a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}=|a_n'|-|b_n'|$.
Then
$$\sum_{\rm sym}(a_{n+1}'+b_{n+1}')^2=\sum_{\rm sym}(|a_n'|-|c_n'|)^2\le\sum_{\rm sym}(a_n'+c_n')^2=\sum_{\rm sym}(a_n'+b_n')^2,$$
where the symetric sum means that each of $a,b$ runs through all (possibly the same) $a,b,c,d$.
The equality holds only if $a_n'=b_n'=c_n'=d_n'=0$.
So, $\sum_{\rm sym}(a_n'+b_n')^2$ is decreasing unless $a_n'=b_n'=c_n'=d_n'=0$, in which case $a_{n+1}=b_{n+1}=c_{n+1}=d_{n+1}=0$.

With our assumption, $\sum_{\rm sym}(a_n'+b_n')^2$ only takes non-negative integer values;
hence it cannot decreases forever, and we are done.

Comment: +1. Nicolás Vilches's answer seems to suggest that with integers there may be an arbitrarily large number of steps needed, even if your approach shows each must eventually  terminate.  For example, multiplying $0,1,q(q-1),q$ by $5768$ and then rounding gives $0,5768,8904,10609$ which takes $25$ steps to reach $0,0,0,0$

Answer (score 5):

This is not true in general. The key observation is that if the sequence stops for some initial condition $(a, b, c, d)$, then it stops for $(\lambda a+\mu, \lambda b+\mu, \lambda c+\mu, \lambda d + \mu)$.

Let
$$ q=\frac{1}{3} \left( 1+\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}+\sqrt[3]{19-3\sqrt{33}} \right)\approx 1.8393 $$
be the unique real root of $q^3-q^2-q-1=0$, and consider
$$ a_1=0, \quad b_1=1, \quad c_1=q(q-1)\approx 1.54369, \quad d_1=q \approx 1.8393. $$
We can easily check that
$$ a_2=1, \quad b_2=q^2-q-1, \quad c_2=2q-q^2, \quad d_2=q. $$
Now, subtract $q$ and then divide everything by $1-q$. Using that
$$ q^2-2q-1=-q^3+2q^2-q=-q(1-q)^2  $$
thanks to $q^3-q^2-q-1=0$, we get
$$ (1, q(q-1), q, 0), $$
which is the initial condition up to a rotation. This way, the original sequence does not stop.

See [*The Convergence of Difference Boxes* by A. Behn, C. Kribs-Zaleta and V. Ponomarenko](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037493) for more discussion in this problem; in particular, they show that this is essentially the "only" counterexample.

Comment: +1 though I am not sure your "subtract $1$ and then multiply everything by $q/(1-q)$" quite works when applied to $q$ as it seems to give $-q$ rather than $q$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the document is gold, I would accept your answer too if I could.

Comment: @Henry I think now it is fixed, sorry about that.